# Difference between setRepeating and setInexactRepeating of AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

What are the parameters of the following:

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
```

And of the following:

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

What is the difference and also how are the two different in terms of functionality?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Both examples schedule a repeating alarm that will send the given `alarmIntent`. On both cases, the first time it is sent will be immediate (`calendar.getTimeInMillis()` returns [the current time](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_gettimeinmillis.htm)). On both cases, the device will be woken up when the alarm needs to be sent (as evident by `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`).

There are two differences between these calls. The simpler one is that the intent will be sent every fifteen minutes on the first call, and every day on the second call (as you can see in the third parameter). The more complicated difference is the function call itself: `setRepeating` will schedule the first alarm for **exactly** every fifteen minutes; `setInexactRepeating` will schedule the second alarm for **approximately** every 24 hours, meaning it might deviate from that interval - with the advantage of consuming less power.

Do notice that this has changed in API 19, where these two calls are synonymous. See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), and [this API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: So if I target SDK 18 and kip my Max sdk 19, do I have to code for both separately?

Comment: Also if I am binding a service to be invoked after the alarm is fired, do I need to acquire a wake lock?

Comment: Whether to code for both cases separately is your decision, and based on your necessities. What I can tell you is that the behavior of `setRepeating()` matches the behavior of `setInexactRepeating()` only when `targetSdkVersion` is 19. For any lower `targetSdkVersion`, their behaviors differ.

Comment: In the context of the given `alarmIntent`, the device will stay awake. If you are to leave the context, the device might go back to sleep. So, for example, if your `alarmIntent` starts an activity, it's certain the device will be awake for the activity to handle the intent. But if you then want to start a service from your activity by calling `startService()`, then yes - you must take a wake lock to ensure that the service will start. [See this for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905099/alarm-does-not-wake-up-my-service).

Answer (score 20):

**Decide how precise your alarm needs to be**

Choosing the alarm type is often the first step in creating an alarm. A further distinction is how precise you need your alarm to be.

For most apps, **`setInexactRepeating()`** is the right choice. When you use this method, **Android synchronizes multiple inexact repeating alarms and fires them at the same time**. This reduces the drain on the battery.

For the rare app that has rigid time requirements as example, the alarm needs to fire **precisely** at 4:00 p.m. everyday then use **`setRepeating()`**.

Reference: [Decide how precise your alarm needs to be](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)

Comment: very good explanation specially about `setRepeating()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

To augment previous answers, there are a number of other best practices to consider when using repeating alarms, particularly inexact alarms requested using `setInexactRepeating()`.

**Alarm Type**

- Non-WAKEUP alarms are better than WAKEUP alarms from a power management perspective. Using the former your alarm may fire late, but it will still fire either when the device is woken by the user, or when another wakeup alarm fires. Using WAKEUP alarms will wake the device out of sleep, consuming additional battery and potentially causing other inexact alarms to fire that have been delayed that could otherwise have been delayed longer (reducing the batching power-saving benefits that inexact alarms provide).
- Prefer alarms using the ELAPSED timebase rather than the RTC timebase. The former are more likely to have a more random distribution across devices than RTC alarms, which reduces the risk of network congestion and on the server if the alarm is triggering some sort of poll. Phones running Gingerbread (or older) suffer from a bug whereby RTC inexact alarms have a tendency to align closely to the real-time clock, e.g. approximately 30s past each quarter of an hour. ELAPSED alarms don't suffer from this bug on these earlier platform versions. Even if your alarm doesn't trigger any network activity, remember that if it is a wakeup alarm it may trigger other alarm non-wakeup intents that may hit the network.

**Timebase**

- Be careful to specify the requested start time in the correct time domain for the alarm type. Failure to do this can result in alarms being set in the past (they fire right away) if setting an RTC alarm with an ELAPSED timebase or far in the future if setting an ELAPSED alarm using the RTC timebase. You can check what alarms an app has scheduled using `dumpsys alarm` via the `adb shell`.

**Interval**

- Specifying an inexact alarm interval of anything other than the interval constants defined in the AlarmManager API is redundant on SDK <19: they will be scheduled as exact not inexact alarms, losing all the power-saving benefits that inexact alarms provide.

Edit: here's further explanation of the bug relating to gingerbread and honeycomb 3.0 devices: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31550

Answer (score 4):

**setRepeating is more accurate** and **setInexactRepeating is for saving battery but no accurate** , setInexactRepeating is good for maintenance in background for example and setRepeating is necessary for example for alarm clock .

Answer (score 0):

Use setInexactRepeating() is used when app is not seriously used to required for example wake up early in the morning . if Alarm wake up approximately that time there is no any life dangeous. 
like medicine pills app where highly critical patient use that app to reminde nurse or doctor staff the is compulsory to use  setRepeating().
 When you use setInexactRepeating()
then  Android synchronizes repeating alarms from multiple apps and fires them at the same time(once). This reduces the total number of times the system must wake the device.
thus reducing drain on the battery.
repeating alarms are inexact. Note that while setInexactRepeating() is an improvement over setRepeating() also 
it can still overwhelm a server if every instance of an app hits the server around the same time. Therefore, for network requests, add some randomness to your alarms.