# My repeat alarm does not work after wifi disconnected

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-wifi

My device does not have a sim card or any network, Except wifi connection.

Now I am setting repeat alarm for daily which working fine when wifi is connected, But it does not trigger on time when wifi is not connected on the Android tablet.

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, archiveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
        val alarms = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarms.cancel(pendingIntent)
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
```

Here are my observations:

1. Let say I set an alarm at 7:10 PM and when device time change to 7:10 PM it got the call as expected when wifi is connected all the time.
2. Now the same scenario in which alarm set for 7:10 PM but when device time change to 7:10 PM but at that time wifi is not connected, Now after 7:11 I turn on my wifi on the device, Just after I connected wifi my previous set alarm got called in this case.

Can anyone know what could be reason alarm does not trigger in time when wifi not connected?

**NOTE:** In my alarm broadcast I am starting WorkManager which had a constraint that it should start only if there is wifi network connected, But I believe that WorkManager should not affect my alarm trigger.

Comment: I really hope you meant "wifi" in the title, not "wife". :D

Comment: ohh yeah type mistake :) @Rohit5k2

Comment: So... do your problem remain when using the examples provided here under the subtitle 'Examples of elapsed real time alarms'? https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21234007/7579123)

Its nothing to do with wifi, its the way you set it up, try with `setRepeating` instead of `setInexactRepeating`. The difference has explained nicely on above answer.

**Edit**

Eventually got it working after changing the flag to 0 like below

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, archiveIntent, 0)
```

Passing 0 will bring any existing alarm back or create a new one.

Comment: I tried that but the results are same, unfortunately, Also I want to stick with setInexactRepeating event through it will add some drift in time that fine.

Comment: Have you tried with setting the flag to 0 like following code 

`val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, archiveIntent, 0)`

Comment: Yup, Now it's got the trigger. Add this in your answer.

Comment: Good job. I added it to my answer so it will help someone in future.